# Untyped decorator makes function "add" untyped [misc] (celery & mypy)

Tags: python, celery, mypy

I do not own the decorator.

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery("tasks", broker="pyamqp://guest@localhost//")


@app.task
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y
```

> tasks.py:6: error: Untyped decorator makes function "add" untyped  [misc]

Why?

Comment: the error is telling you why, because the decorator is untyped

Comment: This is not duplicate, this is different question because I not own the decorator.

Comment: I bet that ChatGPT would not mark as a duplicated. Stackoverflow used to be a better place.

Comment: your question is *why*, which is answered by the duplicate. whether the decorator comes from a third-party library does not change why this is happening.